# how to retrieve data from xml file based on its schema

Tags: c++, xml

```
 char *xsd__schema; /* required element of type xsd:schema */
 char *__any;
```

In my C++ project, I have read the XML schema into a string : xsd__schema, and also read the xml file into a string : __any. how can I retrieve the data into C++'s variant from the string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand the context of your question (are you trying to validate your xml?  or just get data from it?), but either way your answer likely lies in using a 3rd party XML parsing library, lest you spend a fruitless part of your life reinventing the wheel.  There are several quality cross-platform XML parsing libraries which support schema validation:

- [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)
- [libxml++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489403/796027) can you raise an easy example?  I now have get the XML schema,  I want to generate a C++ class to read the XML file based on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a small-size xml-parser you can use [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/):

> TinyXML is a simple, small, C++ XML parser that can be easily integrating into other programs.

It can use files or just parse the xml from a buffer as you're having.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489541/796027) I just want some third party libraries designed to get data from xml files

Comment: Yes... that's what TinyXML is. It is a xml parser that can extract data from a xml-file.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489541/796027)I just google it, it is really a library, I'll try it, thx.